# What is the unit of the velocity in react native?

Tags: react-native

I am having some issues developing a feature for an app I'm working on.

Here is the goal: develop a coverflow using the FlatList. This component should be able to handle gesture on its view and react accordingly.

What I am using: the PanResponder, and a FlatList.

When I get the call to "onPanResponderRelease" I am able to detect a swipe on the component.

Once I detect a swipe, the goal is to calculate the destination offset to scroll to, using the "scrollToOffset" method of the FlatList, depending on the velocity of the swipe.

I retrieve the velocity from the object "gestureState" received in the "onPanResponderRelease" callback.

My question is in the title, what is the unit of this velocity ? Is it a pixel/ms ?

Thank you for your help, if you need more information to better understand my question tell me.

Comment: Velocity is expressed in points per second: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipangesturerecognizer/1621209-velocity

Comment: Thank you for your comment. After more digging and try outs I found out the unit of the velocity received in the "gestureState" object is in "px/ms"